# Не открываются ссылки в IE, если в домене есть знак _ (ExtJs)

Tags: javascript, extjs

Почему то существует проблема в том что не работает авторизация, когда в домене есть знак _ НАПРИМЕР: (oshibka_new.moll.ru) P.S. если будет (osibkanew.moll.ru) то все отлично.

Вопрос. Ориентировочно, в чем может быть проблема? Куда рыть?

[image: Единственная ошибка]

Comment: в доменах вроде бы только латинские буквы, цифры и знак - (тире) разрешены, не?

Comment: Проблема в том, что знак `_` не может быть частью доменного имени. См. RFC 952.

Comment: А на локальных машинах, тоже не может быть? Почему то все браузеры кушают и ничего.